# Distance from a given point to a hyperbolic curve

Tags: stata, curve-fitting, euclidean-distance

I need to find a way of calculating the point on a fitted curve closest to a given point (or the shortest distance to the curve from a given point).

The equation for the fitted curve is of the form: y = m/(x+a)+c.  I tried to solve it analytically but I get a 4th degree polynomial.

Is there a solution to do this that can be operationalised for some thousands of points (e.g. in stata)?

Answer (score 0):

Try nonlinear least-squares estimation, which can be done in Stata using `nl`.

Comment: Thank you Dimiriy. I did try nl but I couldn't get it to work because some of the simulated observations become negative or on the other side of the asymptotes.

Comment: @Frank Can you post some of your simulated data here? You can use `dataex` from SSC to do that.